# Custom Linux GUI

Tags: linux, user-interface, embedded, operating-system

I'm interested in creating a GUI for a Linux operating system. What I'm trying to do, is, a program *will* be the GUI -- the program will have be quite basic. I think this question will go into Embedded Linux development, but I'm not sure where to start neither the amount of tutorials or help available.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want to write a replacement for X, or a window manager, or just a GUI program that runs maximized in X with no wm?

Comment: I'd just stick something to basic, and write a program that's maximized and won't let you access the OS. My GUI will essentially be a branded GUI instead of showing windows (window manager) and the OS behind. Thanks for your help, Nathon!

Comment: What kind of mebedded processor are you working with, in what primary role?  Lots of embedded Linux boxes have done well with web-only UIs (cf. Linksys and other access points/routers).

Comment: @Nathon ...or a graphical shell that runs on the framebuffer device or...

Comment: @Sam: I'm a little confused. How do you think a normal linux box running X "shows the OS behind", and how do you think that your system will be less dependent? Are you aware that X is a standard not linked to any particular platform?

Comment: I don't think I've added enough detail here. Quoting Nathon's text " just a GUI program that runs maximized in X with no window manager". It's essentially that. I'm a bit new to the embedded area.

Comment: @Sam: The mechanism that a "normal" desktop linux system running KDE or gnome uses to display things on the screen is a complicated, multi-layered beast. Something like `kernel<-driver<-X<-window-manager<-[desktop-manager|program]`. Embedded systems either use the same or something a bit simpler depending on their power and audience. We can't really give any advice without knowing *"At which layer do you hope to intervene?"* and *"What do you hope to gaim by doing this?"* and *"How much man power to you have available?"*.

Comment: This will not be complicated. What I'm aiming to do, is start simple. I'm trying to get into the embedded area; just for simplicity, all I'll do is create a program (the GUI) running a clock, from that I can extend it. Thanks for your help, dmckee.

Comment: @Sam: OK. That looks like either of the answers you're got are reasonable. Be aware, however, that writing a graphical interaction layer--even a simple one--from there is a big task. Not entirely beyond reason for a hobby project, but I'd say the same for a simple compiler or OS.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, dmckee, I really have appreciated your help. One last question, do you have any resources (links) which could benefit me?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking at using Qt with the Linux framebuffer driver.  That way you can have an embedded GUI without the overhead of running an X server.

Answer (score 4):

Already done? [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/)

> > DirectFB adds graphical power to embedded systems and sets a new standard for graphics under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

CodeTyphon can let you easily code, visually design and cross compile GUI applications for embedded linux with custom canvas if you want.

http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147